# How to get the basename of multiple file with the filename pattern in linux docker container

Tags: unix, containers, ls, busybox, basename

I have multiple files with the same name pattern in a directory in my container folder:

```
/report/tsl_report_20210604.csv
/report/tsl_report_20210604.zip
```

I am trying to list down and get the basename. So ouput should be like:

```
tsl_report_20210604.csv
tsl_report_20210604.zip
```

I am using command `ls report/tsl_report_* | xargs basename -a 2>&1` and it's working fine on my local Mac machine but when running the same in container, I am getting the below o/p:

```
BusyBox v1.25.1 (2018-05-30 19:58:18 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: basename FILE [SUFFIX]

Strip directory path and .SUFFIX from FILE
```

I don't have any clue why it's not working in container.Can anyone please pointout.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the stripped down version of basename as part of busybox, you can implement the same result by:

Option 1:

```
ls report/tsl_report_* | xargs -n1 basename
```

Option 2:

```
$ for x in report/tsl_report_*; do basename $x ;done
tsl_report_20210604.csv
tsl_report_20210604.zip
```

Option 3:

```
find ./report/ -name 'tsl_report_*' | xargs -n1 basename
```

Comment: I didn't understand the first option.It's even not working.

Comment: typo, need to remove the redirect "2>&" am updating the post. the -n1 splits on whitespace. that is why your initial command doesn't work